# flask javascript can't print/log jinja2 request.form variable

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

Hi all I'm trying to get the value from flask and print it in javascript.

When I do print with a javascript string variable in my form it prints none.

```
var javascript_variable = "key_name";

 // output is: request
console.log('request'+"{{request.form['"+javascript_variable+"']}}");
```

Also tried

```
 // output is: request
console.log('request'+"{{request.form["+javascript_variable+"]}}");
```

however when I manually type the key name it works.

```
 // output is: request key_information
console.log('request'+"{{request.form['key_name']}}");
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I do not want to hardcode the keyname because the key_name is a changing dynamically

I'm trying to access that variable, so I can populate my select option/checkbox/radiobox option something like <option {% if request.form['key_name'] == "value" %} selected {% endif %} same for checkbox and radio box

Comment: this isn't gona work. you can't combine jinja templating and javascript in this fashion. one is interpreted on the server to write templates and produce the javascript that is run in the browser. so you can't access data available to jinja with a javascript variable as by the time the javascript is running, the jinja data is gone. you should take a step back and describe what problem you're actually trying to solve rather than asking how to make your current solution to the problem work.

Comment: I'm trying to access that variable, so I can populate my select option. I'm trying to do something like 
<option {% if request.form['key_name'] == "value" %} selected {% endif %}
same for checkbox and radio box

Comment: then why are you using javascript? this just seems like you should be using jinja tempalting...

Comment: yes but I'm calling the same function for multiple columns. To avoid repeated code with 1 small variable name change I'm calling a js function passing in the key name

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you can use the flash statements inside the views in flask as follows,

```
@blueprint.route('/something.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def function():
    try:
        flash("Submission successful!")
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
    return render_template('something.html')
```

In jinja, you can access the flash variable in the following way,

```
{% if get_flashed_messages() %}
                {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
                <script>window.alert("{{ message }}")</script>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```